# how to measure fragmentation of all files in a folder or entire file system, except ext#

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, filesystems, measurement, fragmentation

Except ext3 or ext4 (files system which can use fsck), how can I measure the file system fragmentation degree or the number of extents of all files in a folder?

Specifically, I am using f2fs file system.